# Unknown folder %userprofile%\WINDOWS

Tags: windows

I found a folder called WINDOWS (Uppercase) in one of my servers. The folder is inside my %userprofile%. I am sure that I did not create the folder. I worry that the server is compromised, I took it offline.
Has anyone ever seen this folder around? Do you know what is it for?

Comment: `%USERPROFILE%` evaluates to `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\` and inside the user profile folder there is no `WINDOWS` folder unless some application has created it. Thus the error is not unexpected.

Comment: What is in the folder? Be sure you can see system and hidden files and look in it. If it is empty then send it to the recycle bin, reboot, and see if it comes back. Maybe placed there inadvertently by a script or something that profile has run. What security do you have in place on this server to ensure it is secure live AV, endpoint protection, etc.

Comment: I deleted it, did not come back. But in any case I took the machine out. No recent applications were added nor scripts. I ran AV scan on it but noting was found. Anyways thanks, just wondered if anyone had seen it before. There had been no firewall warning whatsoever, but just in case I rather that take it down. The good thing of being on a cloud :) (or the bad thing...:( )